# JTable if any row is selected

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to figure out how to add logic to a JTable via an "if" statement that checks to see if ANY row is selected. I know how to check if a specific row is selected but I can't seem to figure out how to check all rows.

```
if(tbl.isRowSelected(0)){
```

Obviously that is checking for a specific row.

I've also tried something like

```
if(tbl.isRowSelected(0-2000)){
```

This did not work nor did I expect it to work.

The reason for this is that I'm setting up the table so that when the user clicks a row and then hits an "edit" button a second table will appear with more data related to the row they selected. (Gets complicated here with 2D arrays inside of a hash map but I first need to get by this simple problem).

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Do you know what a loop is (ie: `for`, `while`, etc.)?

Comment: Yes Jonny. I could do that but it wouldn't be dynamic. I don't know how many rows there will be.

Comment: Why not use [`JTable#getSelectedRow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow%28%29)? `if(table.getSelectedRow() != -1) { ... }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be possible with a [`ListSelectionModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html), which can be retrieved using [`JTable::getSelectionModel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectionModel())

So you can call `table.getSelectionModel().isSelectionEmpty()` to find out if any row is selected.

Comment: Thanks. I marked this as accepted answer because I believe it answered my question in the easiest way.

Answer (score 3):

**Use :**

```
 table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            // do some actions here, for example
            // print first column value from selected row
            System.out.println(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

use table.getSelectedRow() it returns the index of the selected row
and getSelectedColumn() return the selected columns

and there is getSelectedRows() it return index arrays of selected rows

```
int[] indexs=table_name.getSelectedRows();
//all the selected row are here no need to go throw 
//all your rows to see if they are selected or not
for(int index_row:rows){
   //you code here
 }
```